# CMD script copies Fridays file on Monday

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I am trying to copy a file over when the date modified on it is from yesterday during the week. However, on Monday I would need to copy over Fridays file. I've done something like this in SQL before but not sure about the syntax for this.

```sql
SET @NewDate = DATEADD(d, -1, @OldDate)
IF DATENAME(DW, @NewDate) = 'saturday' SET @NewDate = DATEADD(d, -1, @NewDate)
IF DATENAME(DW, @NewDate) = 'sunday'   SET @NewDate = DATEADD(d, -2, @NewDate)
```

This is the currently what my script looks like:

```
@echo on
set "FileName=...\Desktop\test1\test.txt"

set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "date-yesterday=%dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%"

if not exist "%FileName%" goto FileNotExist

rem Get last modification date of the file.
for %%I in ("%FileName%") do set "FileDate=%%~tI"

rem Compare the first 10 characters from file date string with the last
rem 10 characters from current local date hold in environment variable DATE.
if not "%FileDate:~0,10%" == "%date-yesterday:~-10%" goto FileNotToday

copy /y "%FileName%" "...\Desktop\test2"
goto :EndFileCheck

:FileNotToday
echo The file %FileName% is not from today.
goto :EndFileCheck

:FileNotExist
echo The file %FileName% does not exist.

:EndFileCheck
set "FileDate="
set "FileName="

pause
```

Expected: Tuesday to Friday collect yesterdays file and Monday collects Friday

Actual: Always tries to collect yesterdays file, Sunday/Saturday there is no file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you have two options really.

A) If your date local is set to have the day prepended to the date you can grab that and check if it's Monday.

B) You can use WMIC to check the day of the week, and get a number value back which you can then use to make a decision.

Given I don't know your date locale I'd recomend the secod method.

```
@echo on
set "FileName=...\Desktop\test1\test.txt"

FOR /F %%_ IN ('
  WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek
  ^| FINDStr /I "^[0-6]"
') DO (
  ECHO.%%_
  IF %%_ EQU 1 (
    SET /A "day=-3"
  ) ELSE ( SET /A "day=-1" )
)


echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "date-yesterday=%dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%"

if not exist "%FileName%" goto FileNotExist

rem Get last modification date of the file.
for %%I in ("%FileName%") do set "FileDate=%%~tI"

rem Compare the first 10 characters from file date string with the last
rem 10 characters from current local date hold in environment variable DATE.
if not "%FileDate:~0,10%" == "%date-yesterday:~-10%" goto FileNotToday

copy /y "%FileName%" "...\Desktop\test2"
goto :EndFileCheck

:FileNotToday
echo The file %FileName% is not from today.
goto :EndFileCheck

:FileNotExist
echo The file %FileName% does not exist.

:EndFileCheck
set "FileDate="
set "FileName="

pause
```

Also, I refactored your code to get rid of the `GOTOs` and put the functionally different portions into their own functions:

```
@(SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  echo on
  SET "FileName=...\Desktop\test1\test.txt"
  SET "_eLvl=0"
)

IF EXIST "%FileName%" (
  CALL :Main
) ELSE (
  ECHO=The file %FileName% does not exist.
  SET "_eLvl=1"
)

( ENDLOCAL
  PAUSE
  Exit /b %_eLvl%
)

:Main

  CALL :CheckCurrentDay

  CALL :SetCopyDate

  CALL :CompareFileDateandCopy

GOTO :EOF

:CheckCurrentDay

  FOR /F %%_ IN ('
    WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek
    ^| FINDStr /I "^[0-6]"
  ') DO (
    ECHO.%%_
    IF %%_ EQU 1 (
      SET /A "day=-3"
    ) ELSE ( SET /A "day=-1" )
  )
GOTO :EOF

:SetCopyDate
  echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
  echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
  for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
  del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
  set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
  set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
  set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
  set "_File_Copy_Date=%dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%"
GOTO :EOF

:CompareFileDateandCopy
  rem Get last modification date of the file.
  for %%I in ("%FileName%") do set "FileDate=%%~tI"

  rem Compare the first 10 characters from file date string with the last
  rem 10 characters from current local date hold in environment variable DATE.
  if not "%FileDate:~0,10%" == "%_File_Copy_Date:~-10%" (
    echo The file %FileName% is not from today.
    SET "_eLvl=2"
  ) ELSE (
    copy /y "%FileName%" "...\Desktop\test2"
    SET "_eLvl=!ERRORLEVEL!"
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at that now!

Comment: @Snooley You're welcome, I have posted the code above for you as well in-line with your original code.

Comment: Not sure if I'm being daft here. I set the file date to Friday and the copy worked great, however, for testing I put it to yesterday as well and it doesn't copy it over. Is this because yesterday is a Sunday?

Comment: @snooley Yes, you would have to change your System date to be a valid day other than monday and set the file's date to the day prior to see that work.

Comment: @Snooley you can change your date on the CMD line by typing in `DATE`